# Non-interaction between oscillating dipoles (Feynman lectures I.29)

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, dipole

[In lecture 29 of volume I](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_29.html), Feynman tackles the elementary problem of the field radiated by two oscillating dipoles separated by different distances of the order of a wavelength. He describes the interference patterns that emerge when superposing the fields from both dipoles *independently*. In following chapters, he uses much the same reasoning with n oscillators, with some nice geometrical solutions to the superposition problem.

While I have no issue with the interference logic he describes, I feel he leaves out a potentially important factor. The two dipoles are not actually independent: there is an interaction between them, which is not obviously negligible given the small distances (the field emitted by one affects the oscillation of the other, and reciprocally). Therefore, the actual solution should be more complicated than a superposition of fields from independent dipoles and should include a correction term for the interaction energy (this is what makes the many-body problem grow in complexity quickly).

Is Feynman taking a simplifying assumption by ignoring the interaction between the dipoles? It would be strange because he usually makes sure to mention it when a simplification is made. And here, I see no such mention. How justified would that simplification be? The dipoles being so close to each other=, it appears to me that the interaction should actually be an important factor here.

Answer (score 0):

*You* are making incorrect assumptions about the dipole radiators in Feynman's discussion. The degree of interaction (or lack thereof) between dipole radiators depends on the nature of the radiators. Feynman is not talking about two nearby *atomic* dipole radiators, which might have significant interaction. The kind of radiators he *is* talking about is made clear in Section 28-3 (see Figure 28-1 and accompanying text): they are driven by generators whose influence is much greater than that of the field radiated by a nearby radiator, so that the influence of the latter can be neglected. However, if you have any doubts, you can also imagine that each radiator (with its generator) is enclosed in a Faraday cage (that is not grounded), which would shield each radiator from the radiation of others.

Comment: Hm, can you clarify which incorrect assumption I am making in the question? I never assumed it was an atomic system. Your answer seems to be suggesting that Feynman is indeed making the implicit assumption that the interaction between the dipoles is negligible compared to the driving force of the oscillations (I still find it surprising that he doesn't mention it). Additionally, I doubt that you would get any of the interference patterns discussed if you were to put your radiators in a faraday cage. That would sure make their radiation job harder. Also, Feynman never mentions anything related

Comment: The incorrect assumption is that the interaction between the radiators under discussion is non-negligible, which it can be, and clearly is, since it is being neglected. About Faraday cages (that are not grounded): they shield incoming radiation completely, but not outgoing radiation completely: attenuation (if equal for all radiators) would have no bearing on the interference pattern.

Comment: I was not assuming that the interaction is non-negligible. I was asking if Feynman was implicitly neglecting it and why it is justified; it is the question. Your description of Faraday cages breaks Lorentz reciprocity tho. I think your point on asymmetry for non-grounded cages does hold for static electric fields,  not for EM waves.

Comment: This will be my final comment in this thread. Faraday cages aside (they are off-topic anyway): I have been the editor of The Feynman Lectures on Physics for the past 2 decades, and I can see your point, but I do not consider that Feynman made any "simplifying assumptions" in this case. On the contrary, in my opinion the reason Feynman did not mention possible (significant) interactions of the radiators is because that would be an extraordinary "complicating assumption" that would be particularly out of place in a freshman lecture on EM interference, which is what this lecture was.